# Flattening Dataframe with Multidimensional Array

Tags: python, apache-spark, data-structures, pyspark

I'm currently working on loading an xml file with a complex schema in a dataframe.

```
root
|-- tID: string (nullable = true)
|-- Book: long (nullable = true)
|-- Legs: struct (nullable = true)
     |--Leg: struct (nullable = true)
     |--AssetID: string (nullable = true)
     |--FirstOrder: string (nullable = true)
         |--risk: struct (nullable = true)
             |-- scenarios: struct (nullable = true)
                  |-- scenario: array (nullable = true)
                       |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
                            |-- _sc: string (nullable = true)
                            |-- _sens: double (nullable = true)
     |--SecondOrder: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to flatten the dataframe and found a code snippet online ([here](https://github.com/JayLohokare/pySpark-flatten-dataframe/blob/master/SparkRelationalizeDF.ipynb)):

```
def relationalize(df):
    connector = '-'
    def flattenSchema(schema, prefix=None):
        fields = []

    for field in schema.fields:

        #The field.name is added with `` to handle the case where prohibited characters like '.' are a part of the JSON key
        if '.' in field.name:
            name = prefix + '.' + '`' + field.name + '`' if prefix else '`' + field.name + '`'
        else:
            name = prefix + '.' + field.name if prefix else field.name
        dtype = field.dataType

        if isinstance(dtype, ArrayType):
            dtype = dtype.elementType


        if isinstance(dtype, StructType):
            fields += flattenSchema(dtype, prefix=name)

        else:
            fields.append(name)
    return fields

newDf = df

for col_name in flattenSchema(df.schema):
    newDf = newDf.withColumn(col_name.replace('`', '').replace('.', connector), col(col_name))

for field in newDf.schema:
    if isinstance(field.dataType, StructType):
        newDf = newDf.drop(field.name)
    elif isinstance(field.dataType, ArrayType):
        from pyspark.sql.functions import explode_outer
        newDf = newDf.withColumn(field.name, explode_outer(field.name))

    else:
        continue

return newDf
```

However, the dataframe that I have has 2 elements in the array. When I execute the function it explodes both fields and hence creates duplicate rows.

for example the following:

```
  sc     sens
-----    -----
{1,2}    {a,b}
```

would create the following output:

```
1 a
2 a
1 b
2 b
```

However, required output would be:

```
1 a
2 b
```

I know the issue is with the following code snippet:

```
for field in newDf.schema:
    if isinstance(field.dataType, StructType):
        newDf = newDf.drop(field.name)
    elif isinstance(field.dataType, ArrayType):
        from pyspark.sql.functions import explode_outer
        newDf = newDf.withColumn(field.name, explode_outer(field.name))
```

However, I do not know how to tell that the data attributes are "connected". How do I solve this issue?

Comment: which version of spark do you use ? since 2.4.0 you can use [arrays_zip](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip) to merge two arrays into one according to their indexes. that's probably what you should use first then apply your current code.

Comment: that seems to do the trick! Now only issue is that it creates a new structtype, so i need to find a way to remove the old structtype (given that it is nested i can't simply drop it)